# How to set dynamic separation rule height in twocolumn document?

Tags: two-column

I want that the line height matches the text height.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\setlength\columnseprule{1pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The line must end with the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two columns may be obtained in a different manner, a solution is easy:

```
%\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
%\setlength\columnseprule{1pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength\columnseprule{1pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]